# How to find get_distance_in_miles between geo_locations in cake php 3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

How to find `get_distance_in_miles` between `geo_locations` in cakephp 3

by using field like cake php 2 not by core php query. By this method

```
$data = $this->Restaurant->find('all', array(
                    "fields" => array("get_distance_in_miles_between_geo_locations($lat,$long,Restaurant.latitude,Restaurant.longitude) as distance", "Restaurant.*,RestaurantsType.*"),
                    "ORDER BY" => 'DESC',
                ));
```

Comment: See https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-geo/

Answer (score 1):

You question is not very clear and your code would fire errors in cake2

anyway I guess you have a user defined function and you want to use it. The way to do this in cake3 is:

or you'd better use cake SQL functions

```
 $query = $this->Restaurants->find();
 $query->select([
      'distance' => $query->func()->get_distance_in_miles_between_geo_locations([
          $lat,
          $long,
          'Restaurants.latitude' => 'identifier',
          'Restaurants.longitude' => 'identifier'     
      ])
])
```

Mind that I have changed `Restaurant` to `Restaurants` and `RestaurantsType` to `RestaurantsTypes` to follow cake 3 naming conventions

Comment: I am using same as according to                           $data = $this->Storelocations->find()
    ->select([
    'distance' => "get_distance_in_miles_between_geo_locations($lat,$long,Storelocations.latitude,Storelocations.longitude)"])
    ->select($this->Storelocations)
    ->select($this->Storelocations->Stores);

    // $data = $data->all()->toArray();
     print_r($data);
     exit;

Comment: The first variant should definitely not be used, and not even suggested, as it's an SQL injection vulnerability! In the second example it might be useful to use the second argument of the SQL function call to specify the datatype of the `$lat` and `$long` values, otherwise they will probably be bound as strings.